# Cannot install Evernote Web Clipper Google extension

Tags: google-chrome, evernote

When I click on the "Install Google Chrome extension" link at [Evernote Web Clipper Download](http://www.evernote.com/about/download/web_clipper.php) I arrive at a blank page.  I can view the source and see that the page has content, but there is nothing I can do to initiate the installation.  I have uninstalled and reinstalled Google Chrome.  I had no trouble installing on my other computer.

Any ideas as to what could be getting in my way?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem.  To fix it:

1) right-click on the icon of an existing Chrome extension in the extension bar
2) select "Manage extensions
3) click "Get more extensions"
4) search for "evernote"
5) click on the blue [+ add to chrome] button

That worked for me, hopefully it will work for you!

-Rich